# How to avoid duplicates with the pull-based subscribe model?

Tags: networking, publish-subscribe, p2p, distributed-system

I would like to implement a pull-based subscription model in my P2P protocol. Instead of peers themselves sending the events they have produced to all other nodes, they ask (pull request) other nodes which events interest them. The problem is that this process involves a significant waste of bandwidth since each node will ask all the others for the same events and therefore will receive duplicates.